# Linked List class to build strings, trouble with constructor, java

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm struggling to construct a Linked List object for building strings. My class `LString` is meant to mimic a `String` or `StringBuilder`object. Instead of arrays, it uses a linked list to form strings. I'm unsure of how to form the constructor though.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class LString    {

     // 2. Fields
     node   front;
     //node tail;
     int size;

     // 1. Node class

    private class node {

        char data;
        node next;

        //constructors
        //1. default
        public node (){
        }

        //2. data
        public node (char newData){
             this.data = newData;
        }

        //3. data + next
        public node (char newData, node newNext){
             this.data = newData;
             this.next = newNext;
        }


   }
     // 3. Constructors
    public LString(){
        this.size = 0;
        this.front = null;
    }
   public LString(String original) {
   }

    //  4.  Methods
   public int length() {
      return this.size;
   }
   public int compareTo(LString anotherLString) {
      return 0;
   }
   public boolean equals(Object other) {
      if (other == null || !(other instanceof LString)) {
         return false;
      }
      else {
         LString otherLString = (LString)other;
         return true;
      }
   }
   public char charAt(int index) {
      return 'a';
   }
   public void setCharAt(int index, char ch) {
      ch = 'a';
   }
   public LString substring(int start, int end) {
      return null;
   }
   public LString replace(int start, int end, LString lStr) {
      return null;
   }

    //append
    public void append (char data){

        this.size++;

        if  (front == null){
             front =    new node(data);
             return;
        }

        node curr = front;
        while   (curr.next != null){
             curr   = curr.next;
        }

        curr.next = new node(data);

    }

    //prepend
    public void prepend (char data){
        /*node temp = new   node(data);
        temp.next = front;
        front   = temp;*/

        front   = new   node(data, front);
        size++;
    }

    //delete
    public void delete(int index){
    //assume    that index is valid
        if  (index == 0){
             front =    front.next;
        } else {
             node   curr = front;
             for (int i = 0; i <    index   - 1; i++){
                curr = curr.next;
             }
             curr.next = curr.next.next;
        }
        size--;

    }

    //toString
    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder result    = new   StringBuilder();
        result.append('[');

        node curr = front;
        while   (curr   !=  null){
            result.append(curr.data);
            if  (curr.next != null){
                result.append(',');
            }
            curr = curr.next;
        }

        result.append(']');
        return result.toString();
    }

    //add   (at an index)
    public void add(int index,  char data){
         if (index == 0){
              front = new node(data, front);
         }  else {
              node curr = front;
              for   (int i =    0;  i < index - 1;  i++){
                    curr = curr.next;
              }
              curr.next = new   node(data, curr.next);
         }
     }
}
```

Many of the methods are stubs, so the class will compile with another test file. I don't think I need to include it to find the issue though.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your `LString` constructor in different ways. One way I can think of is to accepting `char[]` and store it in your internal LinkedList. You can take a look at `String` constructors in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to get more ideas.